# "ceremony" vs. "show"

Tags: word-usage

I guess [this](https://youtu.be/9PiaU1QXHlI) could be called a [ceremony](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ceremony).

[image]

Is it reasonable to call it an event or an activity? How about a party, a show or a [gathering](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/gathering)?

Which one is more common? Are there any other words more common could be used here?

Comment: It appears to be a _presentation_. It's not a show, unless the presentation was only a part of a theatrical or musical performance. Similarly, it might be a party if the main purpose of the event was as a social gathering.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. When considering only the 1-min-52-sec clip in the link, where two guys make some speech, some guys gather together for taking photos without any theatrical or musical performance, which word should I use to refer to this kind of event?

Comment: As I said, it's the _presentation_ of one of the awards at an awards ceremony. The whole ceremony could be called an event or gathering.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. Your comments are very helpful. Btw, a [channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUpXpAJZSQA) calls the whole ceremony a **show**.

Comment: I suppose that is using _show_ in the (mainly American) sense of a TV programme

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. In this particular context, "TV program" and "TV show" mean the same thing, right?

Comment: Yes, but, as I indicated, _programme_ is British and _show_ American usage.

Comment: @KateBunting  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The clip is of a single *presentation* at an awards ceremony. The ceremony could be described as an *event* or a *gathering*. When shown on TV, it can be described as a *show* in the American sense of the word, meaning a TV program(me).